# Uneven poles for fence with wood railing?

Tags: wood, screws, fence, railing

What can I do if the steel poles used for a fence are uneven? They're all supposed to be the same height, but for some reason, they're uneven (ie. surface is uneven, the welder din't measure correctly, etc). Every pole has a plate at the top where I can insert screws to hold a 2x4 long piece of wood. The poles and the floor cannot be changed.

What can I do if they're uneven? I was thinking of maybe using washers to fill up the extra space, but there has to be a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I would just use different sizes of pressure treated wood to fill the gaps. You'll have to adjust the thickness based upon the gap. Then cover the front to hide everything.

Comment: A photo would be valuable. This is really an aesthetic question, so shape, texture, etc. are important.

Comment: How big is the gap? This will probably dictate your material.

Comment: You could cut 'notches' in the wood to fit over the tall poles.   It might be less obvious than using fillers on the short poles.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the gap. For very small gaps, washers will work just fine. For larger gaps, cut a piece of wood (same wood as the top rail) to shim the gap, and just screw through it. If the gap is excessively large, you'll want longer screws, or you'll want to screw the shim to the long 2x4 first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use washers on the small gaps and then cut wood to fill the larger gaps. Then I'd fabricate wood skirts with a height equal to the largest gap and put them on each post to hide the washers and wood, making it appears all is straight and level. Good luck.